# How do I expand or collapse all the regions in a project using Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How do I expand or collapse all the regions in a project using Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look in *Edit → Outlining.*

There's the following options:

- Toggle Outlining Expansion - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Toggle All Outlining - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- Stop Outlining - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- Collapse To Definitions - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

*Toggle All Outlining* seems to be the option you need.

Comment: I think Euclid wanted to do this for all files in a solution. There are other threads on this, e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312255/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-collapse-all-regions-by-default .