# How to configure Visual Studio to collapse all regions by default?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, region

When I open a code file in a new code window, I press Ctrl+M,O to collapse everything there. As far as I know this can be done by default, without need to press anything every time. I think I did it once, but can't remember where was this option located.

Comment: Did you mean *expand*?  I thougth the default *was* to collapse it.

Comment: If you started out with having unchecked outlining, you might find yourself in the position where you re-check it and want to test if it worked.  In that situation, any files you already had open will retain its uncollapsed state.  In fact, VS retains that state upon a restart, so you might think your change didn't work.  However, if you open up other files you hadn't had open, it will default to collapsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a last resort if you can't get it to work with settings, you can also write a macro to do this. Check out [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/4a694c02-f930-4787-a231-9b6932cb6121/) for an example on this.

Here is the main information from the link:

You can open the Macro IDE by going to Tools->Macros->Macros IDE.
There should be a module called EnvironmentEvents in project MyMacros.
This code should be added to the EnvironmentEvents Module:

```
Private opened As Boolean

    Private Sub WindowEvents_WindowActivated(ByVal GotFocus As EnvDTE.Window, ByVal LostFocus As EnvDTE.Window) Handles WindowEvents.WindowActivated
        If GotFocus.Document Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If
        If GotFocus.Document.FullName.EndsWith(".cs") And opened = True Then
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.CollapsetoDefinitions")
        End If
        opened = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub DocumentEvents_DocumentOpened(ByVal Document As EnvDTE.Document) Handles DocumentEvents.DocumentOpened
        opened = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Just an addendum to this answer, Macros were removed in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: So that's why I couldn't find it on my VS2015. What now?

Comment: You should put the key info from the link directly in the post. I know this is an older answer, so it's technically ok, but this is low quality as far as how answers are expected now. So a update would be nice.

Comment: @DangerZone I definitely should have added the relevant information from the link to the answer. I have updated the answer with that information now. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

This is possible.  Go to the Tools menu, then select options.

```
Text Editor
 \ C#
   \ Advanced
```

The option is called "Enter outlining mode when files open."
When outlining mode is enabled, your regions are collapsed by default.

Comment: @Peter Ivanov: Right, once you've opened a file, the outlining state gets saved (in the .suo I believe).  The setting only affects files without a view state cached.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried Tools\Options\Text Editor\C#\Advanced and check the "Enter outlining mode" when files open?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I found unchecking the 'Enter Outlining Mode' option would disable all outlining, which was undesirable.

I did find this extension though: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0ca60d35-1e02-43b7-bf59-ac7deb9afbca , the "I Hate #Regions" extension. Available for VS2010-2015, and so far seems to work as advertised.