# Visual Studio - Preference to collapse all sections of code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

As in [Visual Studio - Command to collapse all sections of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982677/visual-studio-command-to-collapse-all-sections-of-code) was pointed out, there are shortcuts to collaps total code.

**Now I was wondering if there is an option in some kind of preference where I can handle this behavior?!?**

What I would like to have is, by default the code should be collapsed and I allways have to open each section.

At the moment its the opposit. Nothing is collapsed and I allways have to collaps all and than open the needed methods/functions.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you try Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# (or whatever you're using) > Advanced and then checking 'Enter outlining mode when files open' under the 'Outlining' subsection?

Having given it a try the collapsed / uncollapsed state seems to be preserved on close of the file though, so you'd still need to use `Ctrl` + `M` + `O` if regions had been expanded previously.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312255/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-collapse-all-regions-by-default) discusses it and the solution looked to be writing a macro, but these are not available in VS2015 unfortunately.